# Style for textField added as subview to cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

In my current iOS project I have added a dynamic cell to my tableView with a label and a textField.  I am using the following code to make the textField:

```
UITextField *inputField;
inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,12,185,30)];
inputField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
inputField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
inputField.placeholder = @"your text here...";
[cell addSubview:inputField];
```

The results look like this:

[image: tableView cells]

My question is how do I style the code generated textFields to look like a regular IB textField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inputField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

Here is the `borderStyle` property [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/borderStyle) for you to check.